# utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 112483: invalid start byte in django?

Tags: django, django-models, view

I deployed my django website which is working fine till today.Now, out of nowhere it starts showing unicodedecodeerror [Check error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OglM.png)

whilw the full traceback is :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/webapp/views.py", line 214, in explore
return render(request,'explore/explore.html',{'query':query,'main':query2,'rank':query3,'sec':query4,'lis':query5,'result':result,'theme':request.user.profile.theme})
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 15, in get_template
return engine.get_template(template_name)
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 34, in get_template
return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 143, in get_template
template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 125, in find_template
template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py", line 24, in get_template
contents = self.get_contents(origin)
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py", line 24, in get_contents
return fp.read()
File "/home/gagan/saporawebapp/Sapora/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 112483: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Do you have custom 500 handlers? Looks like this is being called as part of the exception handling stack

Comment: @IainShelvington yes i have custom 500 handler but how is it producing the error?

Comment: Looks like "explore/explore.html" has some encoding errors. Try stripping the template back to find the issue